# Showing a homomorphism (between $U_5$ and $U_{10}$) is bijective (i.e. isomorphism)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've defined a function $f:U_5 \rightarrow U_{10}$:

$$f(2)=3$$
$$f(2^2)=f(2)^2=3^2=9$$
$$f(2^3)=f(2)^3=3^3=7$$
$$f(2^4)=f(2)^4=3^4=1$$

and this is clearly a homomorphism.

However to show it isomorphism I need to show bijective, which I don't know how to show. Any pointers?

---

$U_5 = \mathbb{Z}_5 \text{ multiplication}\mod 5 = \{1,2,3,4\}$
$U_{10} = \mathbb{Z}_{10} \text{ multiplication}\mod 5 = \{1,3,7,9\}$

Comment: What is $U_n$ here ?

Comment: Any injective (or surjective) map between two finite sets of the same size is bijective.

Comment: @CaptainLama, $U_n = (\Bbb Z_n)^{\times}$, the group of multiplicative units modulo $n$.

Comment: Use the isomorphism $U(2\cdot 5)\cong U(2)\times U(5)\cong U(5)$.

Comment: You verified $2\mapsto 3$, $4\mapsto 9$, $3\mapsto 7$ and $1\mapsto 1$, but fail to see that this is bijective?

Comment: Fail to show, even if it would "seem so". Esp. injectivity.

Comment: I also don't understand whether I need to deal with the other $k$s of $f(2)^k$ somehow.

Answer (score 2):

$U_{10} = (\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^\times = \{1,3,7,9\}$, so $f$ is surjective. Only $1 \in U_5$ is mapped to $1 \in U_{10}$, so $f$ is injective. Therefore $f$ is bijective.
We have only to check the value of $f(2)^k$ ($k = 0,1,2,3$), because $2^4 = 1$ in $U_5$, and $f(2)^4 = f(2^4) = f(1) =1$.

(Added)
Generally, one can prove injectivity of $f \colon G \to H$ by showing $\forall x\ldotp f(x) = 1 \to x = 1$ (1 is identity element), because for every $g, h\in G$, $f(g) = f(h)$ implies $f(gh^{-1}) = f(g)f(h)^{-1} = 1$, $gh^{-1} = 1$ and $g = h$.

Comment: Do I not need to state that for $k \not \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ the $f$ is not defined?

Comment: Why is $1 \rightarrow 1$ enough to show $f$ injective?

Comment: > Do I not need to state that for $k \not \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ the $f$ is not defined?
You don't need to do so, because $2^4 = 2^0, 2^5 = 2^1, \cdots$ and you have already checked that $f(2^4) = f(2^0), f(2^5) = f(2^1), \cdots$ are all defined.

Comment: But I've not stated everywhere that all the higher powers lead to (after modulo) the same numbers that I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the canonical ring homomorphism $\varepsilon \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. Its kernel is $10\mathbb{Z}$; since $10\mathbb{Z}\subseteq 5\mathbb{Z}$, this homomorphism induces a surjective ring homomorphism
$$
\bar\varepsilon\colon \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}
$$
Under a ring homomorphism, units are mapped to units, so $\bar\varepsilon$ induces a group homomorphism $\hat\varepsilon$ from the group of units (under multiplication) $U_{10}$ of $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ to the group of units $U_5$ of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Now
$$
\hat\varepsilon(1)=\bar\varepsilon(1)=1,\quad
\hat\varepsilon(3)=\bar\varepsilon(3)=3,\quad
\hat\varepsilon(7)=\bar\varepsilon(7)=2,\quad
\hat\varepsilon(9)=\bar\varepsilon(9)=4.
$$
The map $\hat\varepsilon$ is clearly bijective, hence an isomorphism of groups.